# Generating a random specific char inside my string with random length

Tags: java

I'm finishing my class where my original adn gets copied into another String, but there is a 10% possibility one random char changes in a random position of the String ADN. This is what I have:

```
String mitosiss = this.ADN;
Random r = new Random();
String a = "ACGT";
int b = ADN.length();
int randd = (int)(Math.random()*1);

if(randd == 0){
    int rand = (int)(Math.random() * ADN.length());
    int randLetra = (int)(Math.random()*a.length());
    this.ADN += a.charAt(rand(a.length()));

    return this.ADN;

}else{
    return "ok";
}
```

So, I'm picking randomly the position in the ADN String where the new char will go, and the random char. I did it that way because the new char needs to be A, C, G or T. And I have a Math random that if its == 10, it will make the change. (I know, the `if` is wrong. It's because I'm running and running my code to see if it's working so I don't have to wait for a 10% to appear.)

How can I implement those randoms to my String AND(mitosiss) to make the change?

Comment: if you want a 10% possibility you would do `Math.random() <0.1` instead.

Comment: so you want to add new A, T, G or C character to this.ADN ?

Comment: Yes thats what I'm trying to do. That's why I did two randoms, one to choose a random position inside the String ADN, and one to chose a random char! But I think it's not correct, because I don't really know how to formulate it to return it, that's why I tried the AND = chatAt thing... but it didnt work out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try like so:

```
public String mutation(String adn) {
    String result;
    StringBuilder adnBuilder = new StringBuilder(adn);
    String a = "ACGT";
    double randd = Math.random();
    if(randd < 0.1){
        adnBuilder.setCharAt((int)(Math.random()*adn.length()), a.charAt((int)(Math.random()*a.length())));
        result = adnBuilder.toString();

    }else{
        result = "ok";
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: I tried it, but it did the same with other methods I tried, it adds a char to the existing ADN, but it's not replacing any of the chars in the String. It should look like: If adn = ACT, result should be AGT, or TGC, or any combination of the String a. It needs to replace one char inside the string, it can be in any position. But I can't add a new char :(.

Comment: just replace in a random position in the adn without adding a new character?

Comment: Adding it from the String a! The thing is, the ADN its just a code I randomly generate, and its composed just by A's, C's ,G's and T's. So the mutation should be and exact copy of the ADN I generate, but sometimes, there's a 10% a mutation could happen. So, it it happens, my original ADN would change, but JUST one ramdon char of the ADN. That's why I gave the example that if mutation happens, and lets say, the original ADn is aaa, mutation could be aac, aga, taa. Like that. Because one random char changes, but ONLY with another A, C, G or T.

Comment: edited! checkout new edition that I made and tell me if it's fit your need

Comment: Thank u so much! I was looking up that "StringBuilder", I haven't used it before. I will study about it tomorrow, thank u so much for your paciente and for teaching me something new. Great!!!!